# Is there a "maskna" and "skipna" in numpy python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, masked-array

I have been searching the web for NaN in Python Numpy arrays and found some things I cannot reproduce. I am using the Anaconda distribution with numpy.version.version == 1.10.4

```
from numpy import NA as NA
```

only  gets me a "cannot import NA". This NA module is mentioned in another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589867/improving-performance-of-operations-on-a-numpy-array)

This same link also mentions `maskna` and `skipna` as NumPy parameters.

> Alternatively, most array constructors (as of 1.7) have the parameter `maskna`, which you can set to True

This claim is also supported by the documentation from [scypy.org](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/neps/missing-data.html#working-with-missing-values)

But again when I try this I only ever get an error:

```
a = np.arange(6, maskna=True)
```

gives me an encouraging "TypeError: 'maskna' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

What is going on? Am I hunting a discontinued feature? Is this replaced by nansum(), nanmean() etc. But the documentation is 1.10.1 that's not far of 1.10.4.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I think they meant ``numpy.ma`` instead of ``numpy.NA`` but I'm not sure. Use ``np.isfinite(array)`` to get all finite values or ``~np.isfinite(array)`` to get all infinite and ``NaN`` values as boolean masks.

Comment: you can also use `mask = np.isnan(array)` or `mask = ~np.isnan(array)` to get nan or not-nan values, then `my_finite_array = array[mask]`

Comment: The last comment of the accepted answer: `
The np.NA stuff apparently did not actually make it into 1.7. – Reid Jul 5 '13 at 20:48`

Comment: @hpaulj I see. But why is it in the 1.10 documentation I linked?
 np.ma with mask certainly works. For many things even nansum(), nanmean() a.s.o work fine. I am just curious as to why i cannot find the documented np.NA.

Comment: That link you found is the first, and only reference I have seen to `np.NA`.  It sounds like a feature that someone proposed, even developed, but which was ultimately rejected.  There is a `ma`, masked array, subclass.  But this `NA` apparently was something more fundamental.

Comment: What you found in the docs is a NEP - a proposal.  Just that, nothing more.